# Support for retina images on imgur image upload in Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, images, retina

It would be nice, if the image upload dialog would offer a checkbox for retina resolution images and then display the images accordingly.

At the moment screenshots taken on my retina display Mac show up twice their size, when uploaded using the built-in imgur image uploader:

[image]

Comment: Mac - who cares?  :)

Comment: Maybe there should instead be a cap on the maximum resolution accepted before the image will upload as oppose to auto-scaling (i.e. if the image is too large, deny the upload). What benefit does a retina screenshot provide that a regular one can't accomplish on this site?

Comment: @War10ck It would be less ugly on high-density screens (which are becoming increasingly common). That's reason enough to upload high density images.

Comment: @Undo I guess I'm questioning whether that would make the site "more usable". It seems like maybe a nice to have? I don't even know if I'd go that far though. It seems like it will provide little if any benefit over the current format.

Comment: @Martin Me. FOR THE MAC!!!!

Comment: @Undo: There is no such thing as _"high density images"_. They're just higher resolution images.

Comment: @MartinJames People who use Macs.  So, a good percentage of app developers and graphic designers.  But the issue isn't really limited to Macs, it applies to any device that will display a web page on a screen that's higher resolution than the `px` of the page (a single CSS `px` gets rendered as 2 or more device pixels).  So that basically every smartphone you can buy nowadays— iOS, Android, or Windows.  And “retina” res is quickly becoming the status quo for laptops as well.  _So the real answer to your question is… **everyone**_.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Upload and then use img tag, to scale down the image. Note that it img doesnt resize it (its still 504px wide), but scales*, i.e. the density increases.

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6m29M.png" width="252">
```

---

*Unless you specify the width bigger than the actual image width.

Comment: Yes, I know. But it would be nice if I would not have to do this by hand :)

Comment: @Martin then a user script will surely help you there )

Comment: It's too bad the site doesn't support inline CSS.  It would be easier to use `style="transform:scale(0.5)"` instead of calculating the width of each image.

Answer (score -1):

I disagree with this suggestion.

What you're basically asking for, is a workaround to shrink higher resolution images.
Uploaded images shouldn't be modified, and should really just be shown as-is.

Start adding workarounds / hacks, and you open pandora's box of feature (hack) requests.

Comment: No, I am not suggesting to shrink the image! I am suggesting to detect it's size and set width and height to half of the size. So the images would appear the right size and resolution on retina and non-retina displays alike.

Comment: ... Which is a workaround, because the actual resolution of the image is higher than you'd be showing, effectively _wasting three quarters_ of the data sent to the client.

Comment: @Cerbrus unless they had high density screens, which are not uncommon...

Comment: @Tim: True, but we can't make assumptions on what kind of screen a user uses.

Comment: @Cerbrus No, but what's bad about accommodating everyone?

Comment: What's bad is that implementing this "fix" is just a workaround that wastes data for a majority of SO's userbase.

Comment: Arguably, screenshots of UIs have a fair amount of solid coloration and smooth gradients.  If this were uncompressed images, sure, it would be a huge waste.  Using PNG compression (the most common for screenshots), we're talking about filesizes that at ~10% larger (highly dependent on the exact content, of course).  _So no, for SO's use-case, and especially SE's (where exact pixels sometimes matter, like on the Graphic Design SE), the waste of high-DPI images is minimal and benefit huge._